# Last column of a table in PDF (iTextSharp) not justified

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I generated a PDF file starting from an HTML page using iTextSharp.
But tables are rendered with the last column not justified, as you can see in the image.

What can I do to fix this?

[image: table in a pdf code-generated]

Here's part of the code:

```
StyleSheet ss = new StyleSheet();
TextReader htmlReader = new StringReader(strHTML);
ArrayList htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(htmlReader, ss);
foreach (IElement el in htmlarraylist)
    {
        document.Add(el);
    }
```

In strHTML there is this HTML code:

```
<TABLE style="WIDTH: 100%" border=1 cellSpacing=1 cellPadding=1><BR><TBODY><BR><TR><BR><TD>1</TD><BR><TD>2</TD><BR><TD>4</TD><BR><‌​TD>4</TD><BR><TD>5</TD></TR><BR><TR><BR><TD>6</TD><BR><TD>7</TD><BR><TD>8</TD><BR‌​><TD>9</TD><BR><TD>0</TD></TR><BR><TR><BR><TD>0</TD><BR><TD>98</TD><BR><TD>7</TD>‌​<BR><TD>5</TD><BR><TD>4</TD></TR><BR><TR><BR><TD>3</TD><BR><TD>2</TD><BR><TD>3</T‌​D><BR><TD>4</TD><BR><TD>5</TD></TR><BR><TR><BR><TD>76</TD><BR><TD>7</TD><BR><TD>9‌​</TD><BR><TD>0</TD><BR><TD>4</TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
```

Comment: Please post the code you use to generate that table.

Answer (score 1):

Ciao

do you use a loop to produce your pdf,? are you sure for each cell you make the appropriate aactions...

```
int howManyCell = ....

for (int i = 0; i < howManyCell + 1; i++) {

                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();

                cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;

                cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;

                table.AddCell(cell);
}
```

Maybe do you use an automatic transformation, without any use of pdf class elements ? In thi case show us the header of your html table and a sample of the first table row, to check out if that is normal

Comment: Please edit your question adding this HTML snippet and the C# code you use.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem!

All those BR tags were messing up my tables! Those were added by a replace hided in another class:

```
Replace("\r\n", "<BR>");
```

Thank you guys for your help!